# Chrome HTML5 video subtitles styling

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

I'm trying to display a HTML5 video with subtitles in Chrome, but if for any reason the `video` element is inheriting some *style properties* the subtitles don't display property.

For example if the `video` element is inheriting the `line-height` property then the subtitles don't transform properly between the mode *minimized* and the mode *fullscreen*.

[image]

Check the [examples page](http://fguillen.github.com/ChromeVideoSubsStyle/)

I'm not able to define proper styles for the `video > track` element.

My main concern: is it possible to manipulate the *styles* of a `video > track` element in Chrome?

An my secondary concern: is this weird behavior of the `line-height` in these elements a Chrome bug or my fault?

Comment: [Chrominium bug thread](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=175235)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until we wait for the issue to be fixed we can use the `:-webkit-full-screen` pseudoselector to change line-height when the video is in fullscreen mode, here's the snippet:

```
video{ line-height: 15px }
video:-webkit-full-screen{ line-height: 30px }
```

I've tried on your test page (http://fguillen.github.com/ChromeVideoSubsStyle/) and it seems to work.

Comment: Working as a charm, not a perfect solution because the `line-heigh` in the `-webkit-full-screen` mode will depend in the screen resolution but it is a very good work-around!